# how to implement map and reduce function from scratch as recursive function in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, reduce

How to implement map and reduce function from scratch as purely functional recursive functions in python? Any specific ideas to solve this in a easy way?

Comment: Just do it..?  (You won't get tail recursion in any case, so I'm not sure I see the point...?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def map(func, values):
    rest = values[1:]
    if rest:
        yield from map(func, rest)
    else:
        yield func(values[0])
```

It's a generator so you can iterate over it:

```
for result in map(int, '1234'):
    print(result + 10)
```

Gives:

```
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: but how to print the output values? for ex: print(map(lambda x:x**2, tuple(range(10)))) returns this <generator object map at 0x000001DA1D3F6258>

Comment: You didn't say anything about printing.

Comment: thank you Peter Wood :)

Comment: def myreduce(func, seq):  # for reduce function
    if len(seq) == 1: 
        return seq[0] # base case 
    else: 
        return func(myreduce(func, seq[:-1]), seq[-1])